# two strange problems

Tags: android, android-layout

I got two strange problems:

1-i'm using `previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);` in an App and it works normally and I tried to use the same method in another App, I found eclipse cross this method with a black line and says this method is deprecated while I'm using the same method in another App and it works correctly without any problems
JAVA CODE:

public class AugReal00 extends Activity {

```
SurfaceView cameraPreview;
SurfaceHolder previewHolder;
Camera camera;
Boolean inPreview;


SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback = new Callback() {   

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;  
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            //Open The Camera
            this.camera = android.hardware.Camera.open();
            this.camera.setPreviewDisplay(this.holder);
        } 
        catch(IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }   
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

        parameters.setSceneMode(parameters.SCENE_MODE_SPORTS);
        parameters.setFlashMode(parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
        parameters.setPreviewSize(width/2, height/2);
        parameters.setPictureSize(width/2, height/2);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.startPreview();
    }
};// end of surfaceCallback Listener

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_aug_real00);

    inPreview = false;
    cameraPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
    previewHolder = cameraPreview.getHolder();
    previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
    previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    //previewHolder.se;
}   

public void OnResume() {
    super.onResume();
    camera = Camera.open();
}// end of OnResume

public void OnPause() {
    if (inPreview) {
        camera.stopPreview();
    }
    camera.release();
    camera=null;
    inPreview=false;
    super.onPause();
}// end of OnPause.
```

2-I wrote a simple program and i found that eclipse gives me the following error

```
syntax error, insert } to complete class body
```

while all the brackets are closed and every thing should work fine. I don't know how to solve this issue.

Comment: if the log tells you insert } then you should do it, you must have missed it, try checking it again, happens to me most of the time when I was starting in programming...

Comment: post your code so that we can see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check your old app sdk version number. The same api can be deprecated in next versions.
2. You have not closed an opened brace. Make sure all the braces are properly inserted.